# Read file using MS Access

Tags: ms-access, file-io, vba, ms-access-2013

I am working on ms access 2013 but found some error. I'm trying to read data from text file but it show error. I search everywhere but not replicate the problem. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Code

```
    Set fs = Application.FileSearch   'Get Error on this line
    With fs
    Debug.Print CABPath
        .LookIn = CABPath
        .SearchSubFolders = True
        .FileName = ConFileNm
        If .Execute() > 0 Then
            For FileNum = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
             Next
        End If
    End With
```

Error Description

```
Run-time error 2455:
You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property FileSearch
```

Comment: Could you also provide us with the error description? And also the LOC that is throwing this error.

Comment: did you get this sorted at the end?

Comment: Could you then, please mark the one that helped you as Answer so other can benefit from it?

Comment: @PaulFrancis accurate answer not in the list

Comment: You could share the answer you have come up with, so we could vote it up?

Answer (score 3):

Application.FileSearch, has been discontinued since 2007 versions. So it would not be available to use on 2013. You have some alternatives like Scripting.FileSystem object. There is some explanation and alternatives in this site : http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/268046-application-filesearch-gone-excel-2007-alternatives.html

Hope this helps ! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are also multiple workarounds for this to be found through google;

```
Function GetFiles(MatchString As String, StartDirectory As String, Optional DrillSubfolders As Boolean = False) As Variant

    Dim Results() As Variant

    ReDim Results(0 To 0) As Variant

    CheckFiles Results, MatchString, StartDirectory, DrillSubfolders

    If UBound(Results) > 0 Then
        GetFiles = Results
    Else
        GetFiles = ""
    End If

End Function

Sub CheckFiles(ByRef Results As Variant, MatchString As String, StartDir As String, Drill As Boolean)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fld As Object
    Dim sf As Object
    Dim fil As Object

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(StartDir)

    For Each fil In fld.Files
        If LCase(fil.Name) Like LCase(MatchString) Then
            If LBound(Results) > 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve Results(1 To UBound(Results) + 1)
            Else
                ReDim Results(1 To 1)
            End If
            Results(UBound(Results)) = fil.Name
        End If
    Next

    If Drill Then
        For Each sf In fld.SubFolders
            CheckFiles Results, MatchString, sf.Path, Drill
        Next
    End If

    Set fil = Nothing
    Set sf = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

You would call this in your form through something like this;

```
Dim FileList As Variant
    Dim Counter As Long

    FileList = GetFiles("*.jpeg", "c:\folder\subfolder", True)
    ' to NOT look in subfoldres:
    'FileList = GetFiles("*.jpeg", "c:\folder\subfolder", True)

    If IsArray(FileList) Then
        With DoCmd
            .SetWarnings False
            For Counter = LBound(FileList) To UBound(FileList)
                .RunSQL "INSERT INTO [mytable] (FilePath) VALUES ('" & _
                    FileList(Counter) & "')"
            Next
            .SetWarnings True
        End With
    End If
```

**NOTE:** Code found through google: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS_Access/Q_28027899.html